# Drag and drop causes problem with frame rate after several usage in android

Tags: android

I am using drag and drop with two linear layouts and transfer my textview from one layout to another by using drag and drop, and then more i do it then more stuttering i faced. Fps drops drastically after 10-15 transfers.
Here is code:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ingredients_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_v"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="dfkdlgkdlsskgdlsgsg" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/result_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </LinearLayout>
```

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
            binding.ingredientsLayout.setOnDragListener(dragListener)
            binding.resultLayout.setOnDragListener(dragListener)

            binding.textV.setOnLongClickListener(ingredientLongClickListener)
    }
```

```
private val ingredientLongClickListener = View.OnLongClickListener {
        val clipText = "clipData"
        val item = ClipData.Item(clipText)
        val mimesTypes = arrayOf(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
        val data = ClipData(clipText, mimesTypes, item)

        val dragShadowBuilder = View.DragShadowBuilder(it)
        it.startDragAndDrop(data, dragShadowBuilder, it, 0)

        it.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        true
    }


    private val dragListener = View.OnDragListener { view, event ->
        when(event.action) {
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> {
                event.clipDescription.hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED -> {
                view.invalidate()
                true
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION -> true
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED -> {
                binding.textV.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                view.invalidate()
                true
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DROP -> {
                view.invalidate()
                    val v = event.localState as View
                    val owner = v.parent as ViewGroup
                    owner.removeView(v)

                    val destination = view as LinearLayout
                    destination.addView(v)
                    v.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                true
            }
            DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED -> {
                view.invalidate()
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
```

I tryed to null all objects after drag ended, less invalidate() methods, use invalidate in coroutine, even postInvalidate in other thread, but nothing changing.
Is that problem with new Api startDragAndDrop()? or too many invalidates(but with custom view i have more view invalidates and it works smoothly)? or problem is deeper?